# Storing JSON data in a database column

Tags: json, database, data-structures, nosql

I have a scenario where a "parameter_id" is one column in database and other column is "parameter_value". 
Now - "parameter_value" can contain key-value pairs which are mostly parameter's metadata apart from ONE ACTUAL VALUE. Is it good idea to store this structure as JSON in "parameter_value" column ? This catch here is the number of metadata key-value pairs may vary for each parameter. Will JSON be a good design to store data ?

I am providing data sample below

eg.

```
parameter_id  :::: parameter_value
============================

distance      :::: {value : 10 , run : 5, walk : 5 }
------------------------------------------

bloodPressure :::: {value : 85 , systol : 120 , disatol : 80, beforeExam : 180, afterExam : 60 }
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This is not the way to do things. You won't be able to manipulate the data stored in the JSON strings without explicitly reading and parsing it. Break the data down into native components for your database. For SQL you'd have a table with distance parameter in columns and an ID column that relates the row to its parent. Similarly for blood pressure or any other parameter. If you're not using SQL use whatever structure gives you direct access to the data.

Comment: Thanks @MikeW, so if I got you correctly, do you mean I should have seperate columns for value, run and walk considering distance parameter ?

Comment: That's the essence of it, but you've tagged `nosql` so columns might not be the right terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see – as long as there is a certain flexibility and variance in the data you are to save – why storing the data as JSON shouldn't be good idea. If anything, it saves you from the hassle that comes with restructuring relational databases and rather let you manipulate your data through the parsing of the json. Based on your sample data, it sure seems like you might take advantage of what a combination of JSON and [nosql](http://nosql-database.org/) could provide you with – especially if you don't like dealing with the rigidity of sql.

edit: Mike's comment to your question is worth considering though -- doing it the way you suggest requires you to put down some work in the parsing and reading of the json, as you can't edit or change the values directly.

Comment: Thanks @Bischoff, can you give any pointers to JSON-noSQL combination ? Also just to let you know, my portal will just display data that I am storing and no edits would be done

Comment: For a nice review of nosql and json I recommend having a look at [this](http://www.couchbase.com/why-nosql/nosql-database) text. Obviously, nosql is (partly) designed to deal with massive amounts of (seemingly) arbritraty data and huge amounts of traffic – factors that might not be of much relevance to your use, but hey... it's always fun to try something new, isn't it?

Comment: Sure @Bischoff, obviously useful after next 2 yrs :)